# Handle ClientAbortException on a specific method in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

When a client aborts a request it throws out a `ClientAbortException`.
According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65423702/4840535), the exception can be catched with `@ExceptionHandler(ClientAbortException.class)`. With that, all methods in that Controller will get handled.

So my question is, how can the `ClientAbortException` be handled for only one specific method in a Controller class?

For example I want the method `with` be handled and `without` not be handled. But currently both would be handled because of `@ExceptionHandler(ClientAbortException.class)`.

```java
@Slf4j
@RestController
@AllArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/report", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class ReportResource {

    private ReportApplicationService reportApplicationService;

    @PostMapping("with")
    public ResponseEntity with(@RequestBody FindReport findReport) throws Exception {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(reportApplicationService.createReport(findReport));
    }

    @PostMapping("without")
    public ResponseEntity without(@RequestBody FindReport findReport) throws Exception {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(reportApplicationService.createReport(findReport));
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(ClientAbortException.class)
    public void handleLockException(ClientAbortException exception, HttpServletRequest request) {
        final String message = "ClientAbortException generated by request {} {} from remote address {} with X-FORWARDED-FOR {}";
        final String headerXFF = request.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR");
        log.warn(message, request.getMethod(), request.getRequestURL(), request.getRemoteAddr(), headerXFF);
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried to add `@ExceptionHandler(ClientAbortException.class) `  above the API resource that you wish to handle?

Comment: @Roland `@ExceptionHandler(ClientAbortException.class)?` needs to be over an exception handler method. In this case it's the `handleLockException` method.